# Rails 3 - Storing Historical Access Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

---

Hello people

I want to know if there is a gem or a plug-in for storing historical access data for an app in rails 3.0.9

the idea is:

- a user logs-in to the system
- then, the user make some actions (show, create, update, etc.) in
  differents controllers

So I need to store

- user id
- class name
- controler name
- action name
- object id (this is the object that has been created, updated, showed, etc.)
- date_time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CentralLogger does something similar, but I don't think it will track the user_id.    I'd recommend using this because logging to a MySQL or PostgreSQL database tends to have some serious performance consequences if you ever want to scale your application.   Logging to MongoDB is going to be much cheaper (and easier to shard and scale as your application grows):

https://github.com/customink/central_logger